# Determining the length of a curve using integrals

Tags: integration

Im having problems solving the following problem.

Determine the distance of the following curve: 
\begin{cases}
x(t)= \cos^3(t),\\ 
y(t)= \sin^3(t). \\ 
\end{cases}
In this case $0 \le t \le 2\pi$

The answer should be $6$

I would be really grateful if someone could of help me understand it.

Answer (score 3):

The length of the curve, known as arc length, is given by
$$L = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{x'(t)^{2}+y'(t)^{2}}\ dt$$
In this case, this gives
\begin{align}
L&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(3\cos^{2}{t}(-\sin{t}))^{2}+(3\sin^{2}{t}(\cos{t}))^{2}} \ dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{9\cos^{4}{t}\sin^{2}{t}+9\sin^{4}{t}\cos^{2}{t}}\ dt\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{9\cos^{2}{t}\sin^{2}{t}(\sin^{2}{t}+\cos^{2}{t})}\ dt\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}3|\cos{t}\sin{t}|\ dt\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{3}{2}|\sin{2t}|\ dt
\end{align}
You can easily verify that $\sin{2t}
\geq 0$ when $t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\cup[\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}]$ and that $\sin{2t}\leq0$ when $t\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]\cup[\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi].$ Therefore
$$L=\frac{3}{2}\left[\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin{2t}\ dt + \int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\sin{2t}\ dt - \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\sin{2t}\ dt - \int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}\sin{2t}\ dt \right]$$
You can also check that the first two integrals are $1$ and the last two are $-1$. Therefore
$$L=\frac{3}{2}(4)=6$$

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the formula imagine a little particle moving along this path. Then at each small slice of time, the particle moves its total speed times time. That is, if the particle's path is described a vector-valued function of time $$\overrightarrow{r}(t) = \left \langle \begin{matrix} \cos ^3 (t) \\ \sin^3 (t)\end{matrix} \right \rangle $$ then we have that $$ \text{d}s = \| r'(t) \| \ \text{d}t $$ so that $$s = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{(x'(t))^2 + (y'(t))^2}  \ \text{d}t$$ From here on, the solution is identical to pwerth's excellent derivation,  so in your case the arc length is $$ s= \int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left (\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \cos^3 (t) \right)^2 + \left (\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \sin^3 (t) \right)^2 } \ \text{d}t $$ $$= \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\left(3 \cos^2(t) \cdot (- \sin(t)) \right)^2 + \left(3 \sin^2(t) \cos(t) \right)^2} \ \text{d}t $$ $$= \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{9 \cos^4(t)\sin^2(t) + 9 \sin^4(t) \cos^2(t)} \ \text{d}t $$ $$=\int_0^{2\pi} |3\sin(t) \cos(t)| \sqrt{\sin^2(t) + \cos^2(t)} \ \text{d}t $$ $$ = 3 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} |\sin(2t)| \ \text{d}t = \frac{3}{2} \cdot 4 = 6 $$